# DATE( ) is causing SQL query to take way too long

Tags: mysql, sql

I am running a query which is taking over 5minutes to produce results. When I change the DATE(NOW)) in the LEFT JOIN to a column it takes 9 seconds. Below is the query with the faster line shown

```
SELECT DISTINCT(rental.id), filmCopy.location fC_id, member.id m_id, filmInfo.title fI_title, member.name, member.surname, member.cellphone, member.telephone, rental.due_back,rental.returned, filmCopy.on_loan_to, filmInfo.folder fI_folder, reservation_date rsrvtn, reservation.id res_id
FROM rental
INNER JOIN transactionSummary ON transactionSummary.id = rental.transactionSummary_id
INNER JOIN member ON member.id = transactionSummary.member_id
INNER JOIN filmCopy ON filmCopy.id = rental.filmCopy_id
INNER JOIN filmInfo ON filmInfo.id = filmCopy.filmInfo_id
INNER JOIN filmPriceBracket ON filmPriceBracket.filmInfo_id = filmInfo.id
AND filmPriceBracket.filmCopytype_id = filmCopy.filmCopyType_id
LEFT JOIN reservation ON reservation.filmInfo_id = filmInfo.id
```

> Much faster  - LEFT JOIN reservation ON reservation.filmInfo_id = filmInfo.id AND
>   reservation.reservation_date = DATE( rental.due_back )

```
AND reservation.reservation_date = DATE(NOW())
WHERE rental.due_back < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)
AND rental.returned IS NULL 
AND filmPriceBracket.filmCopyType_id !=24
AND filmPriceBracket.filmCopyType_id !=23
ORDER BY  fI_folder, rsrvtn DESC, filmCopy_id, rental.due_back
```

The slow query gives me the correct result wheres the fast one is okay but incomplete.
Any suggestions as to why using todays DATE makes it so slow??

For background info it pulls a report of overdue movies as well as reserved (both overdue and not)
Thanks

EDIT

---

Heres what I have trued from the answers below but am getting Error in Syntax..

```
DECLARE @NOW DATE
SELECT @NOW := DATE(NOW())

SELECT DISTINCT(rental.id), filmCopy.location fC_id, member.id m_id, filmInfo.title fI_title, member.name, member.surname, member.cellphone, member.telephone, rental.due_back,rental.returned, filmCopy.on_loan_to, filmInfo.folder fI_folder, reservation_date rsrvtn, reservation.id res_id
FROM rental    
INNER JOIN transactionSummary ON transactionSummary.id = rental.transactionSummary_id
INNER JOIN member ON member.id = transactionSummary.member_id
INNER JOIN filmCopy ON filmCopy.id = rental.filmCopy_id
INNER JOIN filmInfo ON filmInfo.id = filmCopy.filmInfo_id
INNER JOIN filmPriceBracket ON filmPriceBracket.filmInfo_id = filmInfo.id
AND filmPriceBracket.filmCopytype_id = filmCopy.filmCopyType_id
LEFT JOIN reservation ON reservation.filmInfo_id = filmInfo.id
AND reservation.reservation_date = @NOW 
WHERE $where 
AND rental.returned IS NULL 
AND filmPriceBracket.filmCopyType_id !=24
AND filmPriceBracket.filmCopyType_id !=23
ORDER BY  fI_folder, rsrvtn DESC, filmCopy_id, rental.due_back
```

Comment: What database system are you using? Please add an appropriate tag.

Comment: As a best practice you should use IDs for each date (eventually even hours if needed). Thus your input would be a date in any date format you may choose, but the data processing/queries would run on IDs (wayyyyyyyyyy faster). You just need to insert a simple sub-querry to link the dates on the "master" TimeTable

Comment: @Takedasama , not *so* faster, since `datetime`s are usually compared as integers or long integers, unless explicit number of days or similar processing is required. In some systems dates are just eight-digit integers in YYYYMMDD format.

Comment: @lserni totally agreed, but a timespan of 30 years leads to Day ID's of just 4 digits. where last 3 years would use only 3 digits. It's just "best practice" to work with IDs, as these improve speed, whatever these are cast over.

Comment: At those levels you have to take system architecture into account, and you have no guarantee that "4 digits", albeit smaller, will compare any faster that 32 or 64 bit INTs. Many processors used to align data to 64 or even 128 bit boundaries, sacrificing space to achieve faster memory access (but see http://lemire.me/blog/archives/2012/05/31/data-alignment-for-speed-myth-or-reality/ ), or can use faster algorithms to calculate offsets in memory. I believe using IDs instead of dates might well work in some scenarios, but not be cost-effective in general.

Answer (score 2):

You may try to create two variable first that contain the values of `DATE(NOW())` and `DATE_SUB(...)` so that they don't have to be evaluated for every record.

---

Something like this should do in MySQL:

```
DECLARE @NOW DATE;
DECLARE @YESTERDAY DATE;

SELECT @NOW := DATE(NOW());
SELECT @YESTERDAY := DATE_SUB(@NOW, INTERVAL 1 DAY);

...
AND reservation.reservation_date = @NOW
WHERE rental.due_back < @YESTERDAY
...
```

Comment: Depends on the engine. As far as I know, MySQL for instance usually evaluates it once per query. I don't think this has any real impact on his scenario though.

Comment: "Usually", you're very right: at least once, I had one query yield wrong results due to the value of NOW() changing mid-query. There probably is some caching, but it isn't full.

Answer (score 0):

First of all verify that the two query do indeed return the same number of rows (I had this one bite me more than once).

Then, you can avoid `DATE(NOW())` being evaluated for each row by doing - this is MySQL syntax; you did not say what DB you were using -

```
SELECT @DATENOW:=DATE(NOW());
SELECT @DATESUB:=DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)
```

and using `@DATENOW` and `@DATESUB` instead of `DATE(NOW())` and `DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)`.

In general, you want all expressions that yield a constant or almost-constant (NOW() actually *varies* during the query) to be explicitly made constants. You can also do this application side, if you can build the query programmatically:

```
# very pseudo code
query := 'SELECT ... ' + date_format(...) + '...'
run_query( query )
```

Comment: Thanks - can you elaborate on how to use the variable - have tried LEFT JOIN reservation ON reservation.filmInfo_id = filmInfo.id
AND reservation.reservation_date = @DATENOW but get no result.
(Am using MYSQL5)

Comment: It ought to work. `reservation_date` is a type date, is it not? Check out that `@DATENOW` yields the correct value with `SELECT @DATENOW`

Answer (score 0):

by writing`reservation.reservation_date = DATE(NOW())` you are calling NOW() function for every record that meets the filters you defined on where clause, that is the bottleneck for your sql code.

you can define a variable for DATE(NOW()) condition and use it instead.

note: if you are using oracle system you can use **with** clause for passing the variable